# Can I put an anonymous function or code as an attribute in directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, anonymous-function

Can I do something like:

```
<div set-height-to="function(){$(this).css($(".sth-elem").height()}"></div>
```

!!!! I do not want to set height only but things more complicated like watching a CSS style of  an element and set style of this element with some offsets, calculations or more.

I will have a link function inside directive and function out will be called at some places to make my directive much more flexible
How can I bind an anonymous function not Controller function or some JavaScript code as an attribute in directive?

Comment: You shoud use ng-init calling a controller method instead of this workarroud. Or even create a directive specific to solve this issue.

Comment: Or can I extend from an directive to make my code flexible?

Comment: It's not a good pratice using jquery as you are doing, even inside a controller. You should treat this inside of a specific directive. Instead of pass the function, just pass the ID or the class to set-height-to and do the job inside the directive calling the css function

Comment: Yes, you can extend a directive with a `decorator`: [article about directive decorators](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/09/experiment-decorating-directives/)

Comment: You should accept one thing - directives in AngularJS are black-boxes, so any formatting of the directive should happen inside of directive. Trying overcome this fact usually causes headache.

Comment: Decorator is all I needed thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Class.js, I can flexibly extend any directives.

```
(function (define) {
    "use strict";
    define([
        'BaseClass/BaseDirective',
        'BaseClass/Component'
    ], function (BaseDirective, Component) {
        var AnimateWhenHover = BaseDirective.extend({
            $animate: null,
            init: function ($animate, scope, element, attr) {
                this.$animate = $animate;
                this._super(scope, element, attr);
            },
            defineScope: function () {
                var data = this.$scope.$eval(this.$attr.animateWhenHover);

                this.$scope.selector = data.show;
                this.$scope.overAnimation = data.over || "l2r";
                this.$scope.outAnimation = data.out || "l2r";
            },
            defineListeners: function () {
                this.$element.hover(this.in.bind(this), this.out.bind(this));
            },
            in: function () {
                this.$element.css({"width": "auto"});
                this.$animate.addClass($(this.$scope.selector), this.$scope.overAnimation);
            },
            out: function () {
                this.$element.css({"width": "50px"});
                this.$animate.removeClass($(this.$scope.selector), this.$scope.outAnimation);
            }
        });

        return new Component("animateWhenHover", ["$animate", function ($animate) {
            return {
                scope: '@',
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                    new AnimateWhenHover($animate, scope, element, attr)
                }
            }
        }
        ]);
    });
}
(define));
```

Answer (score 2):

In your markup I would do this:

```
<div set-height-to=".sth-elem"></div>
```

And in your directive use this attribute to set the height of the element to the height of the selector that you have passed in.

In your directive's link function you can do something like this (*syntax not verified*)

```
element.css('height', $(attr.setHeightTo).height());
```

Comment: um..that is a example. I want to do something much more than setting height~ btw thanks for answering

Comment: Sure, but you can then do whatever you want with that element, with the plus side that all the DOM manipulation is all done inside the directive...where all DOM manipulations belong.

Comment: If you want to do more, then create more directives. Directives can be a slippery slope if you try to put a lot into them. Keep them simple to start is my suggestion.

Comment: I don't want to have many codes doing similar things all around. This is also a extremely bad practice to have codes doing things really similar. It is very hard to maintain and change implementations.